# Unknown tag return by git describe tags command

Tags: git

I am on a specific branch on my project and my git commit sha is:

```
▶ git rev-parse HEAD                                 
66465022d6f2885bf38d71bed6b56da5b3b163b3
```

Here are all my tags

```
▶ git tag
cluster_command
false_tag
test
```

However, the `git describe --tags` returns something unexpected:

```
▶ git describe --tags
test-17-g6646502
```

Where is this thing coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe which says

> The command finds the most recent tag that is reachable from a commit. If the tag points to the commit, then only the tag is shown. Otherwise, it suffixes the tag name with the number of additional commits on top of the tagged object and the abbreviated object name of the most recent commit.

I guess your current commit (HEAD) is 17 commits ahead of commit g6646502 which is tagged as "test".